# Neovim node-client connect to running nvim instance

Tags: node.js, neovim

The [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/node-client) node-client README has an example on how to use it:

```
nvim_proc = cp.spawn('nvim', ['-u', 'NONE', '-N', '--embed'], {})
```

but there is no reference/example to using an existing *neovim* process.

but the python-client has an option to:

```
nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')
```

I need a process handle via unix socket with `WritableStream` and `ReadableStream`(stdin/out).

`net.createConnection(path)` errors with `ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) for that.

Starting `nvim` with `NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/kek nvim` and the running the following code will trigger a `vsplit` in `nvim`.

```js
var attach = require('neovim-client'); // npm install neovim-client                                                                                           
var net = require("net");

var socket = net.Socket();
socket.connect("/tmp/kek");

attach(socket, socket, function(err, nvim) {
  nvim.command('vsplit', function(err, res) {
    process.exit(0);
  })  
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is this not the accepted answer? Also, as an update, attach sould be called like this `const nvim = await attach({reader: socket, writer: socket});`